# getting infinite loop error while setting useState() ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I have mutliSelect and my case is:
when the Value prop is [] (the multiSelect component get this prop), set my useState also [].

I tried to write something like this:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setSelected([]);
}, [Value]);

<Select
  style={style}
  maxTagCount={0}
  maxTagPlaceholder={maxTagPlaceholder}
  mode="multiple"
  placeholder={placeholder}
  showSearch

  value={selected} // here I tried to put the Value but not working well

  onSelect={(val) => onSelectValueMultiSelect(val, selected, setSelected, options)}
  onDeselect={(val) => onDeselectValueMultiSelect(val, selected, setSelected)}>
  {childrenOptions}
</Select>
```

but I get infinite loop error.

the Value array contains arrays form filter data, and on click 'reset filter' button I want to reset my multiSelect field.

I think the problem is when the setSelected([]) called it's render again the Value so the useEffect called again and again.

My MultiSelect component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './MultiSelect.scss';

import { maxTagPlaceholder, onSelectValueMultiSelect, onDeselectValueMultiSelect } from '../Services';
import { Select, Checkbox } from 'antd';

const MultiSelect = ({ options, style, onChangeHandle, placeholder, Value }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [childrenOptions, setChildrenOptions] = useState([]);
  const { Option } = Select;
  const children = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    options.forEach((option) => {
      children.push(
        <>
          <Option key={option.value}>
            <Checkbox className="multi-select-checkbox" checked={selected.some((x) => x === option.value)} />
            {option.value}
          </Option>
        </>
      );
    });
    setChildrenOptions(children);
  }, [selected]);

useEffect(() => {
  onChangeHandle(selected);
}, [selected]);

useEffect(() => {
  setSelected([]);
}, [Value]);

  return (
    <Select
      style={style}
      maxTagCount={0}
      maxTagPlaceholder={maxTagPlaceholder}
      mode="multiple"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      showSearch
      value={selected}
      onSelect={(val) => onSelectValueMultiSelect(val, selected, setSelected, options)}
      onDeselect={(val) => onDeselectValueMultiSelect(val, selected, setSelected)}>
      {childrenOptions}
    </Select>
  );
};

export default MultiSelect;
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full component? Like you said, setting a state causes a re-render and that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If `Value` is calculated based on `selected` then this `useEffect()` is the issue:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setSelected([]);
}, [Value]);
```

As you said, it will cause an infinite loop as `selected` changes again and again, causing `Value` to change as well and the component keeps re-rendering.

Another place to look for error is in your `<Select>` component callbacks with `onSelect` and `onDeselect`. It is not a good idea to pass `setSelected` as parameter in most circumstances because `useState` [hook has side effects](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17665#issuecomment-567690829). You don't provide the full code here, but I think it is likely that this also causes state change unstably in your component and causes the re-rendering.

Moreover, you have 2 `useEffect()` both have `[selected]` as dependency, so when `selected` changes it will cause duplicate rendering to the component as well. This is, however, not the cause to your primary issue.

Solution could be using only 1 `useEffect()` as follow:

Step 1. Regarding your `<Select>` component callback:

```
onSelect={handleSelect}
onDeselect={handleDeselect}

const handleSelect = (val) => {
  // think about removing setSelected
  onSelectValueMultiSelect(val, selected, setSelected, options);
  // move this here
  onChangeHandle(selected);
  // reset selected here if wanted
  setSelected([]);
}

const handleDeselect = (val) => {
  // think about removing setSelected
  onDeselectValueMultiSelect(val, selected, setSelected, options);
  // move this here
  onChangeHandle(selected);
  // reset selected here if wanted
  setSelected([]);
}
```

Step 2. Refactor your `useEffect()`, using only 1 instead of 3:

```
useEffect(() => {
  options.forEach(...);
  setChildrenOptions(children);
}, [selected]);
```

This is not the cleanest code, but this can be the right direction to solve your very particular issue without knowing much about the rest of the code.